# PHP Mysql exact multiple search in where clause

Tags: regex

I have code which outputs results as following when I search for ID 90 & 2792:

RefID = 90, 290, 2792

I only want exact search; i-e, 90 and 2792. But problem is it also shows all 90(s).

In search box, I type 90 then space then 2792.

My code is:

```
$query = $_GET['query']; 
// gets value sent over search form

$words = explode(' ', $_GET['query']);
$regex = implode('|', $words);


WHERE candidatelist.RefID REGEXP '{$regex}'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
$regex = '(^|[^0-9])(' . implode('|', $words) . ')($|[^0-9])';
```

See the [resulting regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/OfI91w/1).

**Details**

- `(^|[^0-9])` - start of string or any char but a digit
- `(90|2792)` - `90` or `2792`
- `($|[^0-9])` - end of string or any char but a digit.